# A question about number sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Given a sequence of nonnegative numbers $t_1,\ldots, t_n\geq 0$,it satisfies that $\sum_{i=1}^n t_i=1$, and 
$$\left|t_1-\frac{t_n+t_2}{2}\right|+\left(\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}\left|t_i-\frac{t_{i-1}+t_{i+1}}{2}\right|\right)+\left|t_n-\frac{t_{n-1}+t_1}{2}\right|=\epsilon\leq 1,$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small constant.
What is the best upper bound on 
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\left|t_{i+1}-t_i\right|\right)+\left|t_n-t_1\right|?$$
Can we have an upper bound only depends on $\epsilon$? I tried several examples,  the upper bounds are $O(\sqrt{\epsilon})$.